# Problems configuring Amazon Iot Button, 3 long blinking pattern

Tags: aws-iot

I have been configuring manually IotButton devices correctly for some weeks following the steps shown in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-gs.html, with the correct certificate and policy so I have been able to launch a Lambda function, but the last days I am not able to connect them.

I obtain 3 long red blink pattern after a white blink, so checking the faq page (https://aws.amazon.com/iotbutton/faq/?nc1=h_ls) it seems that there is a problem with the answer that the button receives from Aws, but I don't know how to check it.

I have tried to configure a new button with the app in a different account, in a clean environment, but I have the same result.

Any idea about what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advice.

Comment: What is the red blinking pattern? <short, short, short>, <long, short, short> , etc?  Depending on the code from the duration of the blinking lights you can further troubleshoot.

Comment: It's a <long, long, long> pattern. Documentation says that it has received an unknown http response from Aws Iot, but I don't know how to further troubleshoot.

Comment: Poop. What a crud error that one is. "Something's wrong we don't know what's wrong keep pushing button have a nice day." Grrr...

Comment: Same problem here. I've post an issue on their forum. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=271442&tstart=0

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will colaborate in the forum.